# Coffeescript objects, jquery callback and variable scope conflicts and confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Trying to find out best approach to have this work:

```
class Person

  constructor: (@el) ->
    @el = $(el)
    this.bind()

  bind: ->
    @el.find('.something').on 'click', ->
      $(this).hide()       # conflict!
      this.do_something()  # conflict!

  do_something: ->
    alert 'done!'
```

I'm aware I can use the **hash rocket  (=>)** and then access `this.do_something` from within my callback, but then that conflicts with `callback 'this'`, and so jquery is trying to select object, not `element '.something'`. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get `this` to refer to different objects. Use a different identifier, by storing the instance's `this` reference in an auxiliary variable:

```
  bind: ->
    person = this
    @el.find('.something').on 'click', ->
      $(this).hide()
      person.do_something()
```

Comment: That's the best approach? Thanks btw.

Comment: @Zenph Yes, that's the best (most readable) approach. You cannot use `this` to point to different objects in the same context.

Comment: I understand context ;) Was hoping either CS or jQuery had a proxy variable to this for such conflicts.

Comment: It works but is still annoying, I wish CoffeeScript classes used something like `self` rather than `this`!